# YoloV3 object detection with tflite model giving around 160 bounding boxes all tagged with first class from the label text

Tags: android, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

The shape of the tflite model is [1, 2535, 85]. You can find the tflite model [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17wyP3Vy9RG3EC6gZ5LfaCOQFCZaenwBs/view?usp=sharing) and label text [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_Tdb-aggzXEJG1qyjb0e9tbcSlCRnPT/view?usp=sharing).

This is how the bug looks

[image]

This is the project I used https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/tree/master/android with some few changes. The changes are as following

1. Added the tflite model and the text in the assets folder (the label text is already present in the project, its the same)
2. Line 57 DetectorActivity.java

   private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE = "yolov3-tiny.tflite";

   private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE = "file:///android_asset/coco.txt";
3. line 181  tflite/YoloV4Classifier.java

   private static boolean isTiny = true;
4. line 426  tflite/YoloV4Classifier.java (Replace the function to the down below)

This is the code

```
private ArrayList<Recognition> getDetectionsForTiny(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ArrayList<Recognition> detections = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
        Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
      //  outputMap.put(0, new float[1][OUTPUT_WIDTH_TINY[0]][4]);
        outputMap.put(0, new float[1][OUTPUT_WIDTH_TINY[1]][labels.size() + 5]);
        Object[] inputArray = {byteBuffer};
        tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
        int gridWidth = OUTPUT_WIDTH_TINY[0];
        float[][][] bboxes = (float [][][]) outputMap.get(0);
       // float[][][] out_score = (float[][][]) outputMap.get(1);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridWidth;i++){
            float maxClass = 0;
            int detectedClass = -1;
            final float[] classes = new float[labels.size()];
            for (int c = 0;c< labels.size();c++){
                classes [c] = bboxes[0][i][c+5];
            }
            for (int c = 0;c<labels.size();++c){
                if (classes[c] > maxClass){
                    detectedClass = c;
                    maxClass = classes[c];
                }
            }
            final float score = maxClass;
            if (score > getObjThresh()){
                final float xPos = bboxes[0][i][0];
                final float yPos = bboxes[0][i][1];
                final float w = bboxes[0][i][2];
                final float h = bboxes[0][i][3];
                final RectF rectF = new RectF(
                        Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                        Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                        Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                        Math.min(bitmap.getHeight() - 1, yPos + h / 2));
                detections.add(new Recognition("" + i, labels.get(detectedClass),score,rectF,detectedClass ));
                count++;
            }
        }
        Log.d("Count", " "+count);
        return detections;
    }
```

Please I donno where I'm going wrong! Struggling with it since days! Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have previously done project with YOLO v2. I don't know what your model is returning, but if the model returns the typical output of YOLO then I can say that you are not doing enough post processing.

Comment: @SusanThapa What do you mean by post-processing exactly?

Comment: @SusanThapa this YOLO model returns one output tensor of [1, 2535, 85]

Comment: In my implementation I was using 3x3 grid size and my model (which was custom implementation) would output [3, 3, 4, 8] for 4 bounding boxes with 3 classes. Post processing means to process the output as the YOLO outputs the bounding boxes with respect to anchor boxes, you also have to do Intersection Over Union to filter duplicate predictions.

Comment: @SusanThapa So there is nothing wrong with the android code right? It's the issue with the model right?

Comment: In ym usecase the general post processing step was like this (I am literally copying function name from my project). processOutput() -> obtainBoundingBoxes()-> thresholdPredictionForBoundingBox(computeHighestProbabilityClass(computeSoftMax()) -> filterDuplicateObject(filterBasedOnOverlap()). As you can see the post processing was quite involved and I haven't even mentioned the code to visualize the output in screen. So, it's a fairly complicated process. Looking at your code I haven't seen many of that post processing. Maybe YOLO v3 doesn't need that IDK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224559/discussion-between-susan-thapa-and-mrrobot9).